# Nested streambuilder to get data from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have Homepage that show users's posts who I'm following, I want to get users's uid who I'm following from Firestore and go to users collection then posts collection and show latest two posts.

First step we must go to Following collection then get uid for each document.

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MdvA.png)

Second step we must go to users collection then where uid is equal to each uid we got in first step, then get latest 2 two document inside posts (oreder by 'date').

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN4UK.png)

[Third Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQkve.png)

I have tried this code but not working and I get an error:

```
════════ (546) Exception caught by widgets library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 4
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///Users/Mr.3bd/AndroidStudioProjects/app/test/lib/Screens/HomePage.dart:351:48
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

My code:

```
StreamBuilder(
                              stream: _firestore
                                  .collection(FOLLOW_COLLECTION)
                                  .document(widget.myuid)
                                  .collection(FOLLOWING_COLLECTION)
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (context, fir_snapshot) {
                                if (!fir_snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return Center(child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 50.0,));
                                }

                                else if(fir_snapshot.hasError)
                                {
                                  return Center(child: Text("No Data",style: TextStyle(color: GlobalUniversal.purple),));
                                } else {
                                  return ListView.builder(
                                      physics:
                                      NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                      itemCount: fir_snapshot
                                          .data.documents.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        DocumentSnapshot myfollowing =
                                        fir_snapshot.data
                                            .documents[index];

                                        return StreamBuilder(
                                          stream: _firestore
                                              .collection(
                                              USERS_COLLECTION)
                                              .where('uid',
                                              isEqualTo:
                                              myfollowing['uid'])
                                              .snapshots(),
                                          builder:
                                              (context, sec_snapshot) {
                                            if (!sec_snapshot.hasData) {
                                              return Center(child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                size: 50.0,));
                                            }

                                            else if(sec_snapshot.hasError)
                                            {
                                              return Center(child: Text("No Data",style: TextStyle(color: GlobalUniversal.purple),));
                                            }

                                            else {
                                              DocumentSnapshot user =
                                              sec_snapshot.data
                                                  .documents[index];

                                              return StreamBuilder(
                                                stream: _firestore
                                                    .collection(
                                                    USERS_COLLECTION)
                                                    .document(user.documentID)
                                                    .collection(POSTS_COLLECTION)
                                                    .orderBy('date', descending: true)
                                                    .snapshots(),
                                                builder:
                                                    (context, thir_snapshot) {
                                                  if (!thir_snapshot.hasData) {
                                                    return Center(child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      size: 50.0,));
                                                  }

                                                  else if(thir_snapshot.hasError)
                                                  {
                                                    return Center(child: Text("No Data",style: TextStyle(color: GlobalUniversal.purple),));
                                                  }

                                                  else {
                                                    DocumentSnapshot post =
                                                    thir_snapshot.data
                                                        .documents[index];
                                                    int usefulCount = post['Usefuls'];
                                                    int likeCount = post['Likes'];
                                                    int commentCount = post['Comments'];
                                                    return Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.only(
                                                          top: 10.0,
                                                          bottom:
                                                          10.0),
                                                      child: InkWell(
                                                        onTap :(){
                                                          // Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Comments(myapplang: widget.myapplang,myuid: widget.myuid,myfullname: widget.fullname,myimg: widget.uprofilePicUrl,CommentMajCount: widget.CommentMajCount,pid: mypost['pid'],  uid: mypost['uid'], majname: widget.majname, pdoc: mypost.documentID.toString())));
                                                        },
                                                        child: Container(
                                                          decoration:
                                                          BoxDecoration(
                                                            color: GlobalUniversal
                                                                .whiteBG,
                                                          ),
                                                          child: Padding(
                                                            padding:
                                                            EdgeInsets
                                                                .all(
                                                                8.0),
                                                            child: Column(
                                                              children: <
                                                                  Widget>[
                                                                SizedBox(
                                                                  height:
                                                                  10.0,
                                                                ),
                                                                Row(
                                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                                  children: <
                                                                      Widget>[
                                                                    Padding(
                                                                      padding: widget.myapplang == 'ar' ? EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0) : EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                                                                      child: Row(
                                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                        MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                                          Container(width: 35.0, height: 35.0, decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.fill, image: NetworkImage(
                                                                            // user image url
                                                                              user['uimg'])))),
                                                                          SizedBox(
                                                                            width: 10.0,
                                                                          ),
                                                                          Text(
                                                                            '${user['name']}',
                                                                            style: TextStyle(color: GlobalUniversal.blackColor, fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'BalooDa2'),
                                                                          ),
                                                                        ],
                                                                      ),
                                                                    ),
                                                                    IconButton(
                                                                        icon: Icon(
                                                                          Icons.menu,
                                                                          color: GlobalUniversal.blackColor,
                                                                        ),
                                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                                        })
                                                                  ],
                                                                ),
                                                                SizedBox(
                                                                  height:
                                                                  20.0,
                                                                ),
                                                                Padding(
                                                                  padding:
                                                                  EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                                                  child: Text(
                                                                      '${post['text']}',
                                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                                          color: GlobalUniversal.blackColor,
                                                                          fontSize: 16.0,
                                                                          fontFamily: 'Tajawal',
                                                                          height: 1.3),
                                                                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                                                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
                                                                ),
                                                                SizedBox(
                                                                  height:
                                                                  15.0,
                                                                ),
                                                                Visibility(
                                                                  child:
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    '${post['pid']}',
                                                                  ),
                                                                  visible:
                                                                  false,
                                                                ),
                                                                Visibility(
                                                                  visible:
                                                                  _isVisible,
                                                                  child:
                                                                  ClipRRect(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                    BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                                                    child:
                                                                    Image.network(
                                                                      '${post['img']}' != null
                                                                          ? '${post['img']}'
                                                                          : showToast,
                                                                      fit:
                                                                      BoxFit.fill,
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                                SizedBox(
                                                                  height:
                                                                  15.0,
                                                                ),
                                                                Divider(),
                                                                Container(
                                                                  width: 180,
                                                                  height: 40,
                                                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                                                    child: Text(widget.myapplang == 'ar' ? "أكتب تعليق.." : "Write a comment..", style: TextStyle(color: GlobalUniversal.blackColor.withOpacity(0.5), fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: widget.myapplang == 'ar' ? 'Tajawal' : 'BalooDa2')),
                                                                    elevation: 0.0,
                                                                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                                                                    ),
                                                                    color: GlobalUniversal.secondWhiteBG,
                                                                    onPressed: () async {
                                                                      //   Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Comments(myapplang: widget.myapplang, myuid: widget.myuid, myfullname: widget.fullname, myimg: widget.uprofilePicUrl, CommentMajCount: widget.CommentMajCount, pid: mypost['pid'],uid: mypost['uid'], majname: widget.majname, pdoc: mypost.documentID.toString())));
                                                                    },
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    );
                                                  }
                                                },
                                              );
                                            }
                                          },
                                        );
                                      });
                                }
                                return Container(
                                  height: 0.0,
                                  width: 0.0,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
```

Comment: Your `ListView`'s `itemCount` is set to `fir_snapshot.data.documents.length` but in your `itemBuilder` you also use `sec_snapshot` and `thir_snapshot`. Are you sure all of these have the same number of items ? It seems it is not the case and this is why you get a `RangeError` exception.

Comment: No, These haven't the same number of item, maybe there are users haven't posts yet